# Not getting notification (response) Contact Form 7 wordpress plugin

Tags: wordpress, email, notifications, feedback

I've got a weird issue. 
I have a feedback form. SMTP configuration is working. Same as feedback form functions. I DO receive emails from my site. The only issue is: after I fill all field and click 'submit' loading icon appears and rolling for eternity. I still get an email, but the user does not see notification 'Thanks, your email successfully sent'. I do have this option field in my Contact Form 7 plugin filled. 
I just do not get it on my site interface. 
What actually makes it more weird - I get other notifications, like 'Please fill required fields' etc. I just do not see SUCCESS notification.

Any ideas?

Comment: use the network monitor to see what the AJAX call answers, e.g. with firefox : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor